# 'Discard check-out' does not actually discard the check-out

Tags: check-out, check-in

System being used is Sharepoint 2013 on premises.

Users in Accounts have monthly files, to make the new month's file they do the following:

- Open August file.
- Check out file to enable editing.
- File/Save As/rename to September file name.
- Save, checks-in September doc.  Close September file.
- Discard check-out of August file.
- However, the August file remains checked out.

I have checked for other posts on Stack Exchange, but didn't find something specifically addressing this issue.  I found these two posts, but they've not helped.

http://uk.pcmag.com/browsers-reviews-and/41051/feature/how-to-clear-your-cache-on-any-browser  (clear the browser cache) – this is a bit too heavy handed, it loses all saved passwords.  Not certain that this would fix the issue either.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_workspace_development_team/2010/09/30/troubleshooting-checkincheckout-problems-in-a-sharepoint-workspace/  (synchronise the document library) – we don’t have a SYNC button.

I'm grateful for any suggestions.

Regards,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found that by not checking out the original document (i.e. the August file), it was still possible to save a new version of the file (i.e. the September file).

Therefore the final two steps described in the Question were eliminated.  There was no longer any need to:

- Discard check-out of August file.
- However, the August file remains checked out.

Therefore, issue solved.